# handle changes of form fields in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

How to disable submit button unless forms form fields are edited/changed in flutter dart?
I'm able to disable the submit button when form fields are empty but i want to disable it when they are edited

Comment: There is an onChanged method in the TextField & TextFormField widget, which gives you the value of the TextField. You can use value to check whether the user is editing the input or not. D:

Comment: yeah but i want to disable the submit button not track the changes of the form

Comment: You want the submit button to be disabled while editing or after edited ? I am confused here.

Comment: Do you want to keep the submit button disabled until user has entered or selected some value in all form fields?

Comment: yes,....i want to keep the submit button disabled as long as the user does not make any changes....once the user edits any formfield then the submit button should b enabled

Answer (score -1):

For this king operation use Stream or any state management solutions. this is just a basic example. I hope this may help you.

```
    var textValue = "";




    TextFormField(
            onChanged :(v){
             textValue =  v;
              setState((){});
           })


RaisedButton(
      onPressed: textValue.isEmpty
                 ? null
                  : () {
                        // do something
                   },
                child: Text("Button"),
                  )
```

Button will be disabled **onPressed** has null or not implemented!